# What key did I press?

Tags: code-golf

The task is to write code to identify which key is pressed on the keyboard. You can assume that only one key is pressed at a time and that there is a standard US keyboard layout. That is the layout with the @ over the 2.

Your code should output a unique identifier for any key pressed. This includes PrtScn, Scroll Lock, Pause, left Shift, right Shift, left Ctrl, right Ctrl, Caps Lock, Tab, Enter, Enter on the number pad, Num Lock, Insert, Ins on the number pad, Backspace, Del, F1...F12, Esc, left Windows key, right Windows key, Alt, AltGr, application key (context menu) and so on.

Your code should carry on  waiting for key presses and outputting their identity until it is killed.  It should output the identifier as soon as a key is released however. It shouldn't carry out any other action from the key presses it receives and it shouldn't output anything apart from the unique identifier.

In your answer, please show what you code outputs for the following key presses: Tab, Pause, Enter, Enter on the number pad, left Windows key, right Windows key, Insert and Ins on the number pad.

If you have a very different keyboard, the challenge is still to output a different identifier for every single key on your keyboard.

Comment: In JS (browser JS, anyway), it is impossible to check whether certain keys are pressed (e.g. Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock, PrtScn). Does this mean that JS cannot answer?

Comment: @ETHproductions It does indeed. Apologies to JS lovers everywhere.

Comment: Requirements modified after 5 answers are provided (including one now deleted). That's not really fair...

Comment: I don't think it's fair/right to request output for keys that aren't on many keyboards such as Windows key etc.

Comment: @Notts90 Aren't they part of the standard US keyboard layout? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg/400px-KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg.png

Comment: @Notts90 I updated the question which I hope you will like.

Comment: Can I use Linux `showkey` command?

Answer (score 22):

### x86 machine code, DOS executable, <s>29</s><sup>*</sup> 28 bytes

```
FAE464D0E873FAE460D0E073F4D41005212192B402CD2188F2CD21EBE3
```

This is a [COM executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) for [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS), it requires a [IBM PC compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible) hardware.
Particularly an [8042 PS/2 controller](http://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller) or more likely an [emulation of it](https://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean) through [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode).
Long story short, it should work out of the box in any mainstream PC.

The source code is

```
BITS 16

 ;Disable the interrupts so we don't compete with the IRQ 1 (the 8042 main
 ;device IRQ) handler (the ISR n. 9 by default) for the reading of the codes.
 cli

_wait:

 ;Is 'Output buffer full (OBF)' bit set?

 in al, 64h                ;Read the 8042 status register             
 shr al, 1                 ;Move bit 0 (OBF) into the carry flag

jnc _wait                  ;Keep spinning if CF = OBF not set

 ;Read the scan code S
 in al, 60h

 ;Is S a break code?

 shl al, 1                 ;Bit 7 is set if it is
jnc _wait

 ;PART 2

 ;AL = S mod 10h := y, AH = S / 10h := x
 aam 16
 add ax, 2121h             ;Make both quantities in the printable ASCII range (skip space though)

 ;Print y
 xchg dx, ax
 mov ah, 02h
 int 21h                   ;int 21/ah=02 prints the char in DL

 ;DH is still valid here, it holds x. We print it now
 mov dl, dh
 int 21h

 ;Never terminate
jmp _wait
```

I've divided the program into two parts.

The first part deals with the reading of the [scancodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode). Scancodes are numeric values associated with every key.
Note that these are hardware code, they don't depend on the OS or the charset. They are like an encoded pair (column, row) of the key.
Every key has a scancode, even those non-standard weird function keys found on some keyboard (e.g. the "open calc" key).
Some key has multi-byte scancode, they have prefixes designed to make the stream decodificable by just looking at the sequence of bytes.
So each key gets its unique identifier, even CTRL, SHIFT, WinKeys and so on.

Only the "break codes", sent when a key is released, are processed, the "make codes" are ignored.
The formers have the higher bit (bit 7 for a byte) set, so it's easy to recognise them.

The second part deals with the printing of a byte.
Printing is always lengthy in assembly, we have no builtins.
To keep it short, and since it was required to write *an identifier* of the key, I abandoned decimal or hex numerals in favour of a personal encoding.

A byte xy, where x is the higher nibble and y the lower is printed as two successive chars c<sub>0</sub> and c<sub>1</sub> defined as:

c<sub>0</sub> = 0x21 + y
c<sub>1</sub> = 0x21 + x

Note that the lower nibble is printed *first* (this spared me a swap).
The rationale is to map the each one of the 16 possible values of a nibble into consecutive ASCII characters from '!'.
Simply put this is a hex numeral but with

1. The nibbles swapped
2. `!"#$%&'()*+,-./01` as digit(als) instead of `0123456789abcdef`

Running it in [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) and pressing some random key (some of which is a special key but note that as a Windows process DOSBox can't capture all the keys) yields

[image: DOSBox running the key identifier]

Note that this program never terminates (further, it takes complete control of the PC by disabling the interrupts) as I believe was intended by the question (simply there is no killing of processes in DOS).

---

<sup>*</sup> Reduced thank to [CodyGray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132240/what-key-did-i-press/132330?noredirect=1#comment324850_132330).

Comment: Did using the `IN` instruction work out to be smaller in terms of bytes than calling the ROM BIOS interrupts (e.g., `int 16h`, function 10h)?

Comment: @CodyGray Most likely not, the whole loop could be skipped. Somehow I just jumped straight to the `in` instruction. That's actually a very good point you have. If you haven't already, why not post it as an answer? :)

Comment: Well now you're talking crazy! That sounds like a lot more work than just commenting on your existing answer. :-p I'm playing with putting something together. Fun tip, though: when code golfing, `xchg` with the accumulator as one of the registers is 1 byte, so that's better than a 2-byte `mov`.

Comment: Okay, the problem with `int 16h` is that I don't get scan codes for the shift keys, scroll lock, or pause/break (perhaps others), and that is required by the challenge. Your solution of reading the input directly from the I/O works, although it looks like to me it returns the same value for all of the keys in the Ins/Del/Home/End/PgUp/PgDown cluster.

Comment: @CodyGray mmm... I have to look into that. Thank you for reporting!

Comment: *Every key has a scancode*: except for the Fn modifier key on laptop and some desktop keyboards.  It changes what scancode other keys send when you press them.  Or on my [Logitech wireless keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/wireless-combo-mk520), holding Fn+F12 lights up the battery-status LED, without sending any scancodes to the computer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: also PAUSE has some strange behavior, IIUC sending the break code together with the make code on key press, and not sending anything on key release. Or that's what I understood from the PC Game Programming Encyclopedia.

Answer (score 12):

## Java 7 or Higher, <s>246</s> 228 bytes

```
import java.awt.event.*;class K{public static void main(String[]a){new java.awt.Frame(){{addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){System.out.println(e);}});show();setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(0<0);}};}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
class K{
    static void main(String[]a){
        new java.awt.Frame(){
            {
                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                });
                show();
                setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(0<0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*-18 thanks to @OlivierGrégoire for `show()`, `0<0` and `import java.awt.event.*;`*

Which results in:

[image]

Even handles shift-presses for capitalized characters, the windows key, cap locks, etc... You can see it printing the 'modifiers' as well, which are 'held keys'.

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=27,keyText=Escape,keyChar=Escape,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=27,primaryLevelUnicode=27,scancode=1,extendedKeyCode=0x1b] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=192,keyText=Back Quote,keyChar='`',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=192,primaryLevelUnicode=96,scancode=41,extendedKeyCode=0xc0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=9,keyText=Tab,keyChar=Tab,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=9,primaryLevelUnicode=9,scancode=15,extendedKeyCode=0x9] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=20,keyText=Caps Lock,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=20,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=58,extendedKeyCode=0x14] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=16,keyText=Shift,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=16,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=42,extendedKeyCode=0x10] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=17,keyText=Ctrl,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Ctrl,extModifiers=Ctrl,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=17,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=29,extendedKeyCode=0x11] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=524,keyText=Windows,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=91,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=91,extendedKeyCode=0x20c] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Alt,extModifiers=Alt,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_LEFT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=32,keyText=Space,keyChar=' ',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=32,primaryLevelUnicode=32,scancode=57,extendedKeyCode=0x20] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=18,keyText=Alt,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Alt,extModifiers=Alt,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=18,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=56,extendedKeyCode=0x12] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=17,keyText=Ctrl,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Ctrl,extModifiers=Ctrl,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=17,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=29,extendedKeyCode=0x11] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=37,keyText=Left,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=37,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=75,extendedKeyCode=0x25] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=16,keyText=Shift,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=Shift,extModifiers=Shift,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=16,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=42,extendedKeyCode=0x10] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=38,keyText=Up,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=38,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=72,extendedKeyCode=0x26] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=39,keyText=Right,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=39,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=77,extendedKeyCode=0x27] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=96,keyText=NumPad-0,keyChar='0',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=96,primaryLevelUnicode=48,scancode=82,extendedKeyCode=0x60] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=110,keyText=NumPad .,keyChar='.',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=110,primaryLevelUnicode=46,scancode=83,extendedKeyCode=0x6e] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=10,keyText=Enter,keyChar=Enter,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=13,primaryLevelUnicode=13,scancode=28,extendedKeyCode=0xa] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=107,keyText=NumPad +,keyChar='+',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=107,primaryLevelUnicode=43,scancode=78,extendedKeyCode=0x6b] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=109,keyText=NumPad -,keyChar='-',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=109,primaryLevelUnicode=45,scancode=74,extendedKeyCode=0x6d] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=106,keyText=NumPad *,keyChar='*',keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD,rawCode=106,primaryLevelUnicode=42,scancode=55,extendedKeyCode=0x6a] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=34,keyText=Page Down,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=34,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=81,extendedKeyCode=0x22] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=33,keyText=Page Up,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=33,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=73,extendedKeyCode=0x21] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=35,keyText=End,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=35,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=79,extendedKeyCode=0x23] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=36,keyText=Home,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=36,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=71,extendedKeyCode=0x24] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=127,keyText=Delete,keyChar=Delete,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=46,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=83,extendedKeyCode=0x7f] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=155,keyText=Insert,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=45,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=82,extendedKeyCode=0x9b] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=123,keyText=F12,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=123,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=88,extendedKeyCode=0x7b] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=122,keyText=F11,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=122,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=87,extendedKeyCode=0x7a] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=121,keyText=F10,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=121,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=68,extendedKeyCode=0x79] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=120,keyText=F9,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=120,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=67,extendedKeyCode=0x78] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=119,keyText=F8,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=119,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=66,extendedKeyCode=0x77] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=118,keyText=F7,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=118,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=65,extendedKeyCode=0x76] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=117,keyText=F6,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=117,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=64,extendedKeyCode=0x75] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=116,keyText=F5,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=116,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=63,extendedKeyCode=0x74] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=115,keyText=F4,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=115,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=62,extendedKeyCode=0x73] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=114,keyText=F3,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=114,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=61,extendedKeyCode=0x72] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=113,keyText=F2,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=113,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=60,extendedKeyCode=0x71] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=112,keyText=F1,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=112,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=59,extendedKeyCode=0x70] on frame0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62176/discussion-on-answer-by-magic-octopus-urn-what-key-did-i-press).

Answer (score 11):

## HTML (with Javascript), <s>46</s> 31 chars, <s>46</s> 31 bytes

<s>Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418313/how-to-differentiate-between-enter-and-return-keys-in-javascript) to differentiate numpad enter and return, LControl and RControl...</s> Not anymore since apsillers found a way to do it with a signle function call.

```
<body onkeyup=alert(event.code)
```

Specific outputs:

OUTPUTS THAT ARE STILL WITH THE NUMBERS ARE THOSE I CAN'T TEST ON MY LAPTOP
PLEASE WAIT FOR ME TO HAVE ACCESS TO THOSE KEYS

PrtScn -> PrintScreen
Scroll Lock -> ScrollLock
Pause -> Pause
left Shift -> ShiftLeft
right Shift -> ShiftRight
left Ctrl -> ContrlLeft
right Ctrl -> ControlRight
Caps Lock -> CapsLock
Tab -> Tab
Enter -> Enter
Enter on the number pad -> NumpadEnter
Num Lock -> NumLock
Insert -> Insert
Ins on the number pad -> Numpad0
Backspace -> Backspace
Del -> Delete
F1...F12 -> F1 to F12
Esc -> Escape
left Windows key -> MetaLeft
right Windows key -> MetaRight
Alt -> AltLeft
AltGr -> AltRight (kind of buggy, it detects ControlLeft and then AltRight, but it is indeed AltRight)
application key (context menu) -> ContextMenu

EDITs :
1 byte saved on `;` after func call
18 bytes saved thanks to Lil' Bits and ETHproductions, they noticed I forgot to shorten func and var names.
32 bytes saved thanks to RogerSpielker, he noticed I was doing sparated code for no reason; and again -2 bytes : `onkeydown` -> `onkeyup`
1 byte saved : no need for final slash
2 bytes saved thanks to CraigAyre : `with()` function
2 bytes saved thanks to ASCII-only : `key` in place of `which`
4 bytes saved, since we have text, there is no need for `'-'+` (every identifier is unique without this)
1 byte saved thanks to ASCII-only (again) : no more closing symbol `>`
15 bytes saved thanks to apsillers, as said at the top of my answer.

```html
<body onkeyup=alert(event.code)
```

Comment: Wait... how is... Caps Lock... detected? I thought that was impossible... Huh, oh well. PrtScn and SysRq don't work for me, but I'm on a laptop with a small keyboard that uses Fn+End and Fn+Home for those two keys.

Comment: I like this answer but it seems to have some problems. Tab doesn't report anything for me when I test it at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoLPQM . Also F12, PrtScn don't follow this rule "It shouldn't carry out any other action from the key presses it receives and it shouldn't output anything apart from the unique identifier."

Comment: @Lembik using html, it is not really possible to prevent system from using the key. You need to force it not recognizing key inputs with a machine (or system) effective language (like C maybe). And for tab, I don't know what conditions it for working (I mean, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, I don't know how my answer treats traversable keys.

Comment: @Lembik If you view the code in a standalone (not a snippet or fiddle or similar), fullscreen page (e.g., with F11) then it captures Tabs; the fact that it doesn't capture tabs is a function of the state of larger browser environment, not the code being run on the page. As for preventing default behaviors, `<body onkeydown=return!!alert(event.code)>` should do the trick by returning `false` on `keydown`

Answer (score 8):

## Tcl/Tk, 22 characters

```tcl
bind . <Key> {puts %K}
```

Sample run:

[image: keys identified by Tcl/Tk]

Notes:

- No right Windows key on [my keyboard](https://linustechtips.com/main/uploads/monthly_2016_10/20161011_190137.thumb.jpg.f3aec315be58e07c731a74adb08b5473.jpg) ☹ (<s>clever</s> designer put the backlight switch in its place)
- The numeric pad's Insert generates different code based on NumLock's status
- The volume knob generates X.org specific codes, all other are just regular [keysyms](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm)

Answer (score 6):

## Bash with X.org, 21 bytes

```
xev|awk 'NR%2&&/\(k/'
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it since I'm on MacBook on Linux - no PrntScr, no numeric keyboard &all.

`xev` is a tool that outputs mouse and keyboard events under `X.org`. I pipe it to awk, filter even lines (since every key is shown when key is pressed, and then when it's released), and select only those that contain `(k` - this string is in every line that describes pressed key.

Comment: Could you add the example outputs listed in the question please.

Comment: @Lembik all output appears after exiting.

Comment: Ah. That isn't what the spec asks for. I will clear that up now.

Comment: This gives a syntax error now.

Comment: @Lembik I'm sorry for it was a mistake in pasting the right thing. This shall work most of the times, I'm working on improvement (it does stuck for some reason when I press `)`).

Comment: This no longer outputs anything no matter what I do to the `xev` window.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino another typo :c Forgive me

Comment: @BruceForte no, it doesn't, as my code outputs every even line and keysym is pesent in some more possible lines than that with name of key.

Comment: Can you explain your code, please ?

Comment: @Leth see updated answer

Comment: @enedil, it works great. Shortest and greatest! Sweet. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Linux doesn't imply X11.  e.g. this wouldn't work on a text console (use `showkey -s` there :P), or on a pure Wayland GUI desktop.  This is really a bash + Xorg answer.

Answer (score 5):

## C and Win32, <strike>240</strike> <strike>224</strike> <strike>216</strike> <strike>205</strike> <strike>202</strike> <strike>194</strike> 191 bytes

```
#include<d3d.h>
#include<stdio.h>
w[9];p(x,y,a,b){printf("%X",a^b);}main(){w[1]=p;w[9]=p;CreateWindow(RegisterClass(w),0,1<<28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);for(;GetMessage(w,0,16,0);)DispatchMessage(w);}
```

### Outputs

<kbd>TAB</kbd>: `F0008C00F0008`

<kbd>PAUSE</kbd>: `450012C0450012`

<kbd>ENTER</kbd>: `1C000CC01C000C`

<kbd>NUMPAD-ENTER</kbd>: `11C000CC11C000C`

<kbd>WINDOWS-LEFT</kbd>: `15B005AC15B005A`

<kbd>WINDOWS-RIGHT</kbd>: `15C005DC15C005D`

<kbd>INSERT</kbd>: `152002CC152002C`

<kbd>NUMPAD-INSERT</kbd>: `52002CC052002C`

### Explanation

```
#include <d3d.h> // shortest built-in header that includes windows.h
#include <stdio.h> // for printf

w[9]; // space for wndclass-data array

// function castable to the signature of WNDPROC
p(x,y,a,b)
{
    // key and state are encoded in the last two 4-byte arguments to wndproc
    printf("%X",a^b);
}

main(m)
{
    // set minimal window class equivalent data pointing to wndproc above
    w[1]=p;w[9]=p;

    // create the window using the class, with WS_VISIBLE flag
    CreateWindow(RegisterClass(w),0,1<<28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    for(;GetMessage(w,0,16,0);) // filter messages 15 and lower, which fire without input
        DispatchMessage(w);
}
```

### Edits

-16 thanks to @ugoren

-8: changed `WNDCLASS` to `int` array since all 10 members are 4 bytes

-11: partial initialization of wndclass-data array, reduced to 9 elements

-3: use implicit `int` decl for wndclass-data array

-8: remove newline from output format (not required in spec and printf flushes immediately without it); move `RegisterClass` into `CreateWindow` arg, using returned `ATOM`; set wndclass name to `m` which just needs a zero-byte in it to be a valid string.

-3: reuse `w` var for `MSG` data

Comment: Doing the same thing with C++ by using _cout_ wouldn't be much shorter  ?

Comment: @Leth No. `<iostream>` + `std::cout<<a^b<<"\n"` is longer. Plus  I think you'd need to add return types to the function decls, and `m` couldn't be an implicit `int`.

Comment: Save a char with `for(;GetMessage(&m,0,16,0);)DispatchMessage(&m);`

Comment: Also, `p(x,y,a,b)` and `(void*)p` should save some.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 369 bytes

```java
import java.awt.event.*;import javax.swing.*;class F{public static void main(String[] a){JFrame f=new JFrame();f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){System.out.print(e.getKeyCode()*8+e.getKeyLocation());}public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}});f.setVisible(true);f.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);}}
```

This cannot be run with TIO because it uses a graphical interface, but it works on my computer.

```
Pause: 153
Enter: 81
Enter on NumPad: 84
Left Super key: 193 (After disabling the Menu shortcut for my desktop)
Right Super key: 201
Insert: 241
Insert on Numpad: 522948 (I don't have one, but that's what you get when you press 5 with Num lock off. When Num lock is on, you get 812.)
```

## Ungolfed / Explanation:

```java
import java.awt.event.*; // KeyListener, KeyEvent
import javax.swing.*; // JFrame

class F implements KeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame(); // creates a new GUI frame
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {  // puts a KeyListener in the frame with the following properties:

            // Method that runs whenever a key is pressed
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // getKeyCode returns an integer that uniquely identifies the key,
                // but not the location (e.g. LShift and RShift have the same key code)
                // To fix this, I scale up the key code by 8 and add the location,
                // which is always 0-4 (Standard, Left, Right, NumPad, or Unknown)
                // I could have scaled by 5 instead but I wasn't really thinking
                System.out.print(e.getKeyCode() * 8 + e.getKeyLocation());
                // If you want nicer-looking output, just change "print" to "println"
            }

            // Method that runs whenever a printable character is typed (does nothing)
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

            // Method that runs whenever a keyboard key is released (does nothing)
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
        });

        f.setVisible(true); // the frame will only except key presses if it is visible
        f.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); // disables "focus traversal" keys (such as Tab) from actually traversing focus
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it works for the tab key?

Comment: `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);` in your answer will fix this.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I don't know what that does and I don't think I want to :P

Comment: It makes your answer work for the TAB key, as it stands your answer is invalid without it.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see - Tab is a "focus traversal key"

Comment: @musicman523 If you switch your `KeyListener` for a `KeyAdapter` you don't have to declare `keyTyped` and `keyReleased`. Adapters extend all Listener methods for you (with nothing in them), so you can just override the methods you want.

Comment: @LordFarquaad Thanks for the advice. I'm not going to golf this any further because I would just end up with [the other Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132253/69054)

Answer (score 3):

## Scala 2.10+, 279 chars, 279 bytes

Now this is a scala response :) even though it feels like I'm doing Java.
Anyway we can't test it on TIO.

```
import scala.swing._
import java.awt.event._
object M extends SimpleSwingApplication{def top=new MainFrame{this.peer.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){def keyPressed(e:KeyEvent){print(e.getKeyCode+"-"+e.getKeyLocation)}
def keyReleased(e:KeyEvent){}
def keyTyped(e:KeyEvent){}})}}
```

It's sad we need to declare all inherited methods even if we don't use them :l can I remove them from byte count, since some compiler flags can permit not declaring them?

This prints (as for my html-js response) the keyPressed, "-" and then its "location".

For instance :

PrtScn -> not verifyable
Scroll Lock -> 145-1
Pause -> 19-1
left Shift -> 16-2
right Shift -> 16-3
left Ctrl -> 17-2
right Ctrl -> 17-3
Caps Lock -> 20-1
Tab -> not verifyable
Enter -> 10-1
Enter on the number pad -> 10-4
Num Lock -> 144-4
Insert -> 96-1
Ins on the number pad -> 96-4
Backspace -> 8-1
Del -> 127-1
F1...F12 -> 112-1 to 123-1
Esc -> 27-1
left Windows key -> 524-2
right Windows key -> 524-3
Alt -> 18-2
AltGr -> 18-3 (kind of buggy, it detects 17-2 and then 18-3, but it is indeed 18-3)
application key (context menu) -> 525-1

Though I think it depends on the computer :/ I'm on an azerty laptop right now.

Comment: If you want to not count the unneeded declarations, you might have to include the length of the non-standard compiler flags.  Unless old compilers used to default to that?  C answers usually need to be compiled with `-std=c89` since modern compilers default to c99 or c11, but don't need to count that.  So I'm not sure what the ruling would be from code-golf meta.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 19 bytes

> **PROGRAM:S**

```
If Ans
Disp Ans
getKey
prgmS
```

- Enter: 105,
- Left key: 24,
- Right key: 26,
- Ins[ert] is a little different because it would normally take two key presses to get to, but those would be 21 followed by 23.

**Here's an illustration of the rest of the keys:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

> **PROGRAM:S**  The editor displays the name at the top apart from the code; the name is "S"

```
If Ans    // If the last input isn't zero
Disp Ans  // Display the last input
getKey    // Input a key press
prgmS     // Call the same program in a recursive fashion
```

This, unfortunately, isn't possible to do in Arnold C, so I had to stick to TI-BASIC.

Comment: Does it work for every key in that picture?  If not which keys does it fail for?

Comment: Yes, it works for every key except the on button, reserved for killing the program without popping a battery out of the calculator.

Comment: @bearacuda13: I have an equal calculator that I bought 18 years ago and didn't knew the ON key detail for years. I had being using it since end of university (11 years ago), but who knows...

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 34 bytes

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey().Character
```

Outputs on the same line as the input, which can be a tad confusing.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 144 + 601 = 745 bytes

Consists of two classes, I couldn't manage to successfully combine them into one class.

Main class:

```c#
namespace System.Windows.Forms{class P:Form{static void Main(){Application.Run(new P());}P(){new Reflection.M().U+=k=>Console.Write(k.f+k.v);}}}
```

Hook class:

```c#
namespace System.Reflection{using Runtime.InteropServices;public class M{public delegate void d(s s);event d u;public event d U{add{if(h<1){j=m;h=SetWindowsHookEx(13,j,Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),0);}u+=value;}remove{u-=value;}}public struct s{public int v;public int c;public int f;}[DllImport("user32.dll")]static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,p lpfn,IntPtr hMod,int dwThreadId);delegate int p(int c,int w,IntPtr l);p j;int h;int m(int c,int w,IntPtr l){if(c>=0&u!=null&(w==257|w==261))u.Invoke((s)Marshal.PtrToStructure(l,typeof(s)));return -1;}}}
```

Outputs:

- Tab: `137`
- Pause: `147`
- Enter: `141`
- NumPad Enter: `142`
- Left Windows: `220`
- Right Windows: `221`
- Insert: `174`
- NumPad Insert: `224`

Comment: I can get the bytes down a bit by changing `||` to `|` and other similar golfs but my brain needs a rest after doing that!

Comment: In the Hook class, I think `public int v;public int c;public int f;` could be shortened to `public int v,c,f;`

Comment: @QuestionMarks Good idea will golf when I get back to a computer

Answer (score 1):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm), 26 Bytes

```
loop{
input,x,L1M
send %x%
}
```

Can't test (win-only), but the `M` option says

> M: Modified keystrokes such as Control-A through Control-Z are recognized and transcribed if they correspond to real ASCII characters.

So it should do fine.

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) + Win32, 94 <del>95</del> <del>98</del> <del>105</del> <del>107</del> <del>110</del> bytes

```
#import"d3d.h"
j;f(){for(;;)for(j=191;j--;)GetAsyncKeyState(j)&(j<16||j>18)?printf("%d",j):0;}
```

The code captures keys even after focus is lost.

The following screenshots are recorded adding spaces between outputs (`printf("%d ",j);` +1 byte) for better readibility:

[image: key screenshot]

<kbd>Left-ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left-win</kbd> <kbd>Left-alt</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Right-alt</kbd> <kbd>Right-win</kbd> <kbd>Right-menu</kbd> <kbd>Right-ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left-shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Right-shift</kbd> <kbd>Left-shift</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Num 1</kbd> <kbd>Num 2</kbd> <kbd>Num 3</kbd> <kbd>Left-shift</kbd> <kbd>+/= (on the main part)</kbd> <kbd>Num +</kbd> <kbd>Left-alt</kbd> <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>

The code uses `GetAsyncKeyState` to query key state without checking message queue, usually more real-time than other user-mode approaches (except DirectInput). This approach is widely used in keyloggers.

`(j<16||j>18)` filters regular Ctrl/Alt/Shift. 16/17/18 is triggered whenever left or right one is pressed, along with location-specified vkey value.

Answer (score 1):

## WinApi C ([gcc](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)), 156 bytes

```
#include <d3d.h>
#define b GetStdHandle(-10)
BYTE i[20];main(){SetConsoleMode(b,0);a:ReadConsoleInput(b,i,1,i+5);*i^1||*(i+4)||printf("%X\n",i[10]);goto a;}
```

This program prints out the [Windows Virtual-Key Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) assciocated with each keyboard key of input. The `\n` in the `printf` format-string is optional (but makes output human-friendly) and can be dropped for a total score of **154 bytes**. An easy way to kill the program (without taskmgr) is with `CTRL + PAUSE`. If you have a keyboard with a Fn key, this program cannot pick it up since it isn't even noticed by Windows.

- Credit to MooseBoys's answer for the `#include <d3d.h>` trick and inspiration for the `BYTE` array.

The program with local variables, readability, and without compiler warnings looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE conIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD ir;
    DWORD useless;

    SetConsoleMode(conIn, 0);

    for(;;)
    {
        ReadConsoleInput(conIn, &ir, 1, &useless);

        if(ir.EventType == KEY_EVENT && !ir.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
            printf("%X\n", ir.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode);
    }

    return 0;
}
```